# Information needed regarding ATA5831 transceiver with AVR microcontroller

Tags: avr, atmel

I am trying to use the Atmel ATA5831 UHF transceiver that has an embedded AVR microcontroller core. The datasheet for the transceiver is here: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-9285s-Car-Access-ATA5831-ATA5832-ATA5833_Datasheet.pdf. 
I don't have much experience with using AVR microcontrollers but I have worked on many other microcontrollers. It is not mentioned in the datasheet what type of AVR microcontroller is present in the IC, so I am just posting this topic in this forum. Now the problem I am facing is that it is repeatedly mentioned in the datasheet that the transceiver can be sent into Tx mode or Rx mode by some EEPROM setting like on Pg. 13 of datasheet. But what exactly is the EEPROM setting, what are the functions or commands to acheive this, that is totally unclear. Also some service based concept is mentioned in the datasheet on pg 11 but how do we select the required service is not given. If anyone has worked with this transceiver or knows some documentation or how to do the above, please help me out. I am totally confused here..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is only the **datasheet summary** (Atmel always has a full datasheet and a summary).

The strange thing is that there is no full datasheet available (maybe for 'security' reasons, because the IC is used in car locks)

Contact Atmel and if you recieve the full datasheet upload it somewhere...